# Hibernate inserting data in batch, can it be stopped?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I have a situation where I have to do about 25000 insertions in the DB.
The primary key is generated using a DB sequence.
I can see that first it tries to generate 1000 unique ids and then inserts 1000 records in the DB.
Is there a mechanism to stop this ?

Comment: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ_NAME")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_NAME", sequenceName = "SEQ_NAME", allocationSize=10)
    @Column(name = "RATEQUOTEID", nullable = false)
    private Long rateQuoteId = null;

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Remember to keep this int = 0, so hibernate doesn't think that you are trying to update an existing row.

Comment: int is out of question because the column value is too huge to accommodate in it

Comment: Can you use a long instead then? If it's bigger than a long, then I reckon you'd have to use a UUID.
An int goes up to 2,147,483,647, while a long can go up to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807. 
A UUID can hold up to 2^128 values.